# Prove that $1^2-2^2+3^2-…+(-1)^{n-1} n^2$=$(-1)^{n-1}\frac{ n(n+1)}{2}$ whenever n is a positive integer using mathematical induction.

Tags: solution-verification, induction

I am wondering if the third to last equation is correct, where I factored out the $(-1)^k$. The first term is inside the parenthesis is $(-1)^{-1}$. Is this correct? If I multiply it out again, wont the $(-1)$'s cancel? I'm not 100% sure even though i proved it. I am assuming $(-1)^k$ multiplied by $(-1)^{-1}$ is $(-1)^{k-1}$
[image: Proof]

Comment: Correct${}{}{}$

Comment: Agreed. Well done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is completely correct.

Comment: where did the $(-1)^k$ go between lines 1 and 2